# Class method is not a function?

Tags: javascript, function, class, methods, typeerror

I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: this.time_to_x is not a function" when incorporating some open source ES5 code into my ES6 Class.  Here is the class (I've removed some of the bulk, but most of the essential stuff is there).  Assume Diamond() is called.  It's this line that gets the error: x = this.time_to_x(frame.time);

Why is time_to_x() not being considered a function?

```
export default class TimelinePanel {

  constructor(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.ctx_wrap = ctx; 
  }

  create (ctx) {
    this.rect({ctx, x: 20, y: 15, width: 130, height: 10}); // ***
    this.drawLayerContents();
  }

  Diamond(frame, y) {

    var x, y2;

    x = this.time_to_x(frame.time);
    y2 = y + LINE_HEIGHT * 0.5  - DIAMOND_SIZE / 2;

    var self = this;
    var isOver = false;

    this.path = function() {
        this.ctx_wrap
            .beginPath()
            .moveTo(x, y2)
            .lineTo(x + DIAMOND_SIZE / 2, y2 + DIAMOND_SIZE / 2)
            .lineTo(x, y2 + DIAMOND_SIZE)
            .lineTo(x - DIAMOND_SIZE / 2, y2 + DIAMOND_SIZE / 2)
            .closePath();
    };
  }

  drawLayerContents() {
    // ...
    for (i = 0; i < il; i++) {
        // ...
        for (j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            // Dimonds
            frame = values[j];
            renderItems.push(new this.Diamond(frame, y));
        }
    }
  }

  y_to_track(y) {
    if (y - MARKER_TRACK_HEIGHT < 0) return -1;
    return (y - MARKER_TRACK_HEIGHT + scrollTop) / LINE_HEIGHT | 0;
  }

  x_to_time(x) {
    var units = time_scale / tickMark3;
    return frame_start + ((x - LEFT_GUTTER) / units | 0) / tickMark3;
  }

  time_to_x(s) {
    var ds = s - frame_start;
    ds *= time_scale;
    ds += LEFT_GUTTER;
    return ds;
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `Diamond()`?

Comment: Please show how you're calling `Diamond`. You are very likely not binding `this` to the right object.

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your problem, but the way you are defining `this.path` inside `Diamond` is incorrect. `this` inside that function will not be what you want it to be. The simplest way to fix that problem is to write `this.path = () => {` using an arrow function.

Comment: @torazaburo @4castle - Diamond is being called from within another Class method like this:
`renderItems.push(new this.Diamond(frame, y));`

Comment: If it is called from another class, then it is likely that `this` is an instance of that other class, not an instance of TimelinePanel. So it does not have the members of `TimelinePanel`. `this` depends on the way a function is called (and a "method" is just a function attached to an object property).

Comment: Please learn about [how `this` behaves in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). It's very different from other languages. If your confusion is resulting from the `class` syntactic sugar, you may want to [stop using the `class` syntax](https://github.com/joshburgess/not-awesome-es6-classes) until you understand how to write the equivalent code that doesn't use it.

Comment: @QuentinRoy - Diamond is called from the same Class.  I've updated the sample code above to show this.  the Class method create() is called from another Class, then create() calls drawLayerContents() in this class, which then calls Diamond() in this class.

Comment: @4castle - thanks, okay, I will continue to read up on `this` more (I already have, and thought that I did understand it).  Trying to understand it more now with this example ... I need to continue using Class here and now in this project, as this is just one small piece of code in a much larger architecture of classes

Comment: @4castle - thanks for the link, that is good info

Comment: You are creating a instance of this `Diamond` class when you do `new this.Diamond(frame, y)`. As a result, inside the function, `this` is this new instance, not the instance of `TimelinePanel` where it has originally been created from. Hence, `this` does not have the members of `TimelinePanel`.

Answer (score 4):

You are creating an instance of `this.Diamond` class when you do `new this.Diamond(frame, y)`. As a result, inside the function, `this` is this new instance, not the instance of `TimelinePanel` where it has originally been created from. Hence, `this` does not have the members of `TimelinePanel`.

Because it seems `y_to_track` and `x_to_time` does not make use of `this`, you could make them static (add the keyword `static` before them) and call them as follow: `TimelinePanel.y_to_track`.

If you need to access methods bound to a particular instance of `TimelinePanel`, then I don't see any other solution than passing this instance to the `Diamond` constructor or refactoring `TimelinePanel` and use closure around the `Diamond` constructor.

In any case it seems you are trying to replicate the behavior of Java-like internal classes (e.g. where you can access the container class instance with `ClassName.this` or just access the container class members), there is no such things in JS (at least with `class`).

EDIT: I just noticed that you are accessing `TimelinePanel`'s `ctx_wrap` member that you will not be able to put as class member. The easiest seem to pass the `TimelinePanel` to the `Diamond` constructor: `Diamond(frame, y, panel)` and `new this.Diamond(frame, y, this)`. It puts into question the usefulness of adding `Diamond` as a member of `TimelinePanel`.

Comment: @Quentin_Roy - Thanks!  Using static and TimelinePanel.time_to_x works! Solved!

Comment: Not yet exactly sure what you mean about ctx_wrap.  So far there is no error, it is works.  But will keep what you say in mind if I have more issue.s

Comment: In the `path` method attached to each new `Diamond` instances, you are using `this.ctx_wrap`. It won't be defined for `Diamond` instances.

Answer (score 1):

Because the way you have it it's supposed `time_to_x` from closure, not from `this`. In `this` there is no such function, so `this.time_to_x` name returns `undefined` which is not a function indeed.

I suggest smth like this:
put `var self = this;` inside the class but outside of the `Diamond` method.
Then call `self.time_to_x()` inside `Diamond`.

Comment: okay, thank you!  so what is the correct solution to call methods within other methods of a class?

Comment: I have other methods in the same class that are calling other methods in same way with this. This works:

`create () {
    this.myFunction();
 }

myFunction () {
    var x = 1;
    var y = this.nextFunction(x);
    console.log("test " + y);
 }

 nextFunction(x) {
    return x * x;
 }`

Comment: ^ sorry, mini-Markdown for code does not seem to be working above

Comment: I don't understand this answer. `Diamond` is a method; calling `this.otherMethod()` from inside it should work fine. There is no need for a `self` variable. The most likely problem is actually that `Diamond` itself is not getting called with the proper this, most likely because it is being used as a callback as in `someFunc(panel.Diamond)` instead of `someFunc((frame, y) => panel.Diamond(frame, y))`.

Comment: @Battle_Slug - see comments above

Comment: @Battle_Slug - `var self = this` is already inside of Diamond, so can I use self2 outside in the class?  Tried that, and did not seem to work.  I tried inside the constructor() and outside the constructor.

Comment: @torazaburo - Diamond is called like this: `renderItems.push(new this.Diamond(frame, y));`  I've updated the sample code above to show how Diamond is called. Another class calls the create() method in this class, then create() calls drawLayerContents() in this class, which then calls Diamond() in this class.